What regions of Japan call this mythical creature “okuri-inu” vs “okuri-ōkami”?
I have been researching a yokai that, when it appears in canine form, is often called either “okuri-inu” (送り犬) or “okuri-ōkami” (probably 送り狼 but I haven't seen the kanji in sources). “Yama-inu” (山犬) is also a common variant. The typical legend has it following travelers at night on mountain or forest roads, keeping its distance unless the person trips. If that happens, it pounces and rips them apart, though it can be fooled if the person pretends they were just sitting down for a rest. Despite the risk, it can actually be a good companion since nothing else will bother a person being followed by this powerful creature, and in some versions they actively protect humans. Travelers who reach home safely can send the yokai away by calling out, “Thank you for seeing me off.” This is where the “okuri” ("sending off" or "seeing off") part of the name comes from, which combined into okuri-inu or okuri-ōkami makes it the "sending off dog" or "sending off wolf," respectively. A final offering of food is also considered a good idea.
Many sources say the legends are found from Tohoku to Kyushu, with the terms implied to vary by region. However, they do not say which regions use which terms, except for a weasel version (okuri-itachi) that occurs on the Izu peninsula and in Saitama.
I have found a few sources that seem to mark regions using “dog” vs “wolf,” but I’m not sure how much to trust them. Wikipedia uses “okuri-ōkami” when describing legends in the Kantō and Kansai/Kinki regions plus Kōchi Prefecture in Shikoku. It then uses “okuri-inu” and “yama-inu” for two areas in Nagano Prefecture. One of those areas, Koumi, is specified to use “okuri-inu” for a version that protects people and “mukae-inu” for those that attack people. The source for this information is Yōkai jiten by Murakami Kenji. I haven't found an accessible English translation and I don't know enough kanji to read the original if that is available, however, so I can’t confirm it. Based on my notes, the Wikipedia page also recently switched “okuri-inu” to “okuri-ōkami” for the Kantō/Kinki/Kōchi entry, so I’m suspicious of reading too much into it.
Meanwhile, an E-Budo forum includes an entry that talks of hearing “several tales of okuri-okami from around Nara.” Whether the author uses that term because it is connected to the region or because of personal preference is not clear. However, I have seen other information on wolf-worship in the Nara area, particularly Tamaki Shrine where they were considered divine messengers, so it’s possible they used “okuri ōkami” for this powerful creature that was only dangerous if you didn’t follow its rules.
I would appreciate any help in clearing up the question of what regions use “okuri-inu” vs “okuri-ōkami” in their local legends. I’ll take any level of specificity, whether it’s narrowed down by town, prefecture, region, or even just general directions like north or southwest to help me ground this legend in its geographic context.

I'm voting to close this question because it's far more than just a question of dialect or language. This is not a particularly well-known yokai. If the information on Wikipedia is insufficient, the matter likely falls entirely within the realm of expert research about culture.

I was worried that might be the case. I originally posted this on Mythology and Folklore.SE and someone thought I might have better luck over here. Perhaps I should try HiNative or some other resource outside of Stack Exchange?

Unfortunately, this is the kind of question that the average Japanese Internet user would not be able to answer. HiNative is also a language support forum, so I don't think it will meet your expectations. I found that 怪異・妖怪伝承データベース allows you to search yokai folklore by region.

The database you suggested allowed me to answer my question. Since it is more appropriate for the Mythology.SE, I posted my findings as an answer there.

Asked and answered at https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/11071/what-regions-of-japan-call-this-creature-okuri-inu-vs-okuri-%C5%8Dkami
